# Creating a condition to prove data already exists in a database using an if statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

In the `script` in question I'm able to do all that I want to do except prove that an email exists in the database. I know I'm missing something, leaving something out. In this question I'm only showing the code that doesn't work. The rest of the `script` works. I think the issue is in the `if` statement, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```php
if(empty($_POST['email']))
{

    $query_email = "
         SELECT
         email
         from users
         where
         email = :email
    ";

    $query_goes = array(

    ':email' => $_POST['email']

    );
    try
    {

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query_email);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_goes);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) 
    {
        die("This email is already in use...");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: So, `print_r($row)`, what do you see?

Comment: You're running the query if it IS EMPTY! Try NOT EMPTY `if(!empty($_POST['email']))`

Comment: I created a way to manage users. If an admin wants to change an address. I want the script to let them know if that e mail address is in the system. When I add any data such as name, last name, it errors out email already exists. I'm missing something in the if statement.  If I change the email to a new email it works--no error.  Array ( [email] => marksb@fun.com ) after issuing this print_r($row); That's the current email address of the person I'm trying to update. Fake of course.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
//...
}
```

This way your if statement will be executed, because  $_POST['email'] is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have forgot  the binding

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query_email);
 $stmt ->bindValue(':email',$_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It'll take your advice and make the changes to my code. I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks for the help.